# Stop Mac Mail message body from auto completing email addresses

Tags: macos, mac, autocomplete, apple-mail

Every time I type to an "@" symbol it auto completes the rest of the email address.  The problem is that I have more than one email address that is like mylastname@domain.com.  I have several of those and it keeps auto completing with the same email. I can't even type over it because the minute i type anything after the "@" sign it completes the domain.

I can't seem to find where to change this setting.

Comment: Doesn't the Delete key remove the auto-complete, and allow you to type what you want?

Comment: lol - nope... the second I type anything it just autocompletes again.

Comment: I use Apple Mail daily and I've never seen this. Email addresses don't autocomplete in the body, and any autocompletion in the headers can be overtyped. Are you sure you don't have some substitutions defined in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text?

Comment: That's the answer!

Comment: You should submit that as an answer so i can mark this solved and give you credit!